# Unable to deploy multi container app in Azure functions app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am working on a task where I wants to host multiple functions in single function app. I see there is a docker compose option available but it doesn't seems to be working for me.

I have the below docker compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  functionv1:
    image: functionpoc:v1.0.0
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
  functionv2:
    image: functionpoc:v2.0.0
    ports:
      - "3001:80"
  functionv3:
    image: functionpoc:v3.0.0
    ports:
      - "3002:80"
```

As soon as I save deployment center settings app becomes unreachable and I cannot see functions created.

Any suggestion on what's going wrong here? Feature is in preview so not sure if this has been tested by someone earlier.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I opened MS case and support engineer told me that functionality was only rolled out for web app with containers not function app but since both are using app service plan, feature got accidently enabled for function app as well but can’t be used right now.

Answer (score 0):

> Deploying a multi-container application to Azure Functions using Docker Compose. However, this feature is still in preview and may not be fully stable yet.

```
To troubleshoot the issue
```

1. Check the logs of the container to see if there are any errors or issues that are preventing it from starting up.
2. And check the ports that you are using in your Docker Compose file are not already in use by other services or applications. By default, the container in which your function app runs uses `port :80`. When other services in the same container are also trying to using `port :80`, the function app can fail to start.
3. Deploy each function separately to see if they work individually.

   Modify Docker compose file.

Open docker-compose.yaml in a text editor. The file configures the  `azure-vote-back`  and  `azure-vote-front`  services.

```
version: '3'
services:
  azure-vote-back:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/bitnami/redis:6.0.8
    container_name: azure-vote-back
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"

  azure-vote-front:
    build: ./azure-vote
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1
    container_name: azure-vote-front
    environment:
      REDIS: azure-vote-back
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
```

For further information refer to the [MSDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-multi-container-apps) and [MSDoc2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose.md)

Comment: Thanks for the response but no matter what I do, I always get the error 
2023-03-27T08:36:15.047Z INFO  - Pulling image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.6-appservice-stage5
2023-03-27T08:36:15.340Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.6-appservice-stage5 not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by \"4-python3.6-appservice-stage5\" is not found"} 

I am not using the image I see anywhere in my code.

Comment: The reason for this error is that the image you are trying to use is not available in the registry you are using. You can try to check if the image exists in the registry by running the following command in the terminal:

    docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.6-appservice-stage5

If the image is not found, you can try to use a different image or registry.

Comment: And another possible reason for this error is that there is a typo or error in your Docker Compose file.  You can validate your Docker Compose file using the following command:

    docker-compose config

Comment: I cannot find that image in MS registry itself so not sure how we can even dowload MCR function app reference https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/azure-functions/python/about

Error response from daemon: manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.6-appservice-stage5 not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "4-python3.6-appservice-stage5" is not found